If $X_n\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n,p_n)$ and $np_n\rightarrow\infty$ then $\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq \mathbb{E}(X_n))\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$?
Consider a sequence of binomial variables $X_n\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n,p_n)$.

If $p=\frac{c}{n}$ for a constant $c$ then $X_n\rightarrow \mathrm{Pois(c)}$ in probability.
On the other extreme, if $p=c$ then the Central Limit Theorem shows that $\frac{X_n-\mathbb{E}(X_n)}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X_n)}}\rightarrow N(0,1)$. This implies $\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq \mathbb{E}(X_n))\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$.

What happens in between, when $p\gg \frac{1}{n}$ but $p\ll 1$? Can we still apply a certain version of the CLT to conclude $\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq \mathbb{E}(X_n))\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$?

Have you tried the Lindeberg-Feller CLT?

As in this link https://myweb.uiowa.edu/pbreheny/7110/wiki/lindeberg-feller.html

I'd guess the threshold corresponds to the threshold when $\max_x\Bigl[\mathbb{P}[X_n] = x\Bigr] = o(1)$.

If $np_n \to \infty,$ then you in fact get central limit behaviour, with the $L_\infty$ distance from Gaussianity scaling as $1/\sqrt{np_n}$. However, if you're just looking to understand the behaviour of $P(X_n \ge \mathbb{E}[X_n]),$ then we need very little machinery: it is known that the median of a $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ random variable is either $\lfloor np\rfloor$ or $\lceil np \rceil$ [1]. This means that $$ P(X_n \ge \lfloor np_n \rfloor) \ge \frac12, P(X_n \ge \lceil n p_n\rceil + 1) \le \frac12. $$
So, it suffices to argue that as $n \to \infty,$ $$ P(X_n \in \{ \lfloor np_n\rfloor, \lceil n p_n\rceil\}) \to 0. $$ The handwavy calculation here is that if $np_n \to \infty,$ then the binomial mass around $np_n \pm \sqrt{np_n}$ is roughly uniform, so the quantity above is of order $1/\sqrt{np_n},$ which vanishes. The rest of the answer will argue this via an elementary calculation.

We can use the bound here, which essentially comes from Stirling's approximation, that $$ \binom{n}{k} \le \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi n (k/n)(1-k/n)}} \exp(n h(k/n)),$$ where $h(x) = - x \log x - (1-x) \log (1-x).$ Note that $$p^k (1-p)^{n-k} = \exp(k \log p + (n-k) \log(1-p)). $$ So, for any $k$, $$ \binom{n}{k} p_n^k (1-p_n)^{n-k} \le \sqrt{\frac{1}{n (k/n)(1-k/n)}} \exp\left( k \log \frac{p_n}{k/n} + (n-k) \log \frac{(1-p_n)}{1-k/n} \right).$$
Let us define
$$ h_p(x) = x \log \frac{x}{p} + (1-x) \log \frac{1-x}{1-p}.$$ Then note that $$ h_p(p) = 0 \\ h_p'(p)= \left.\log \frac{x}{p} - \log \frac{1-x}{1-p}\right|_{x = p} = 0\\ h_p''(x) = \frac1x + \frac1{1-x} \ge 4,$$ where the last inequality uses $x (1-x) \le ((x + 1-x)/2)^2$. So, $h_p(\cdot)$ is a strongly convex function (called relative entropy), and in particular, $h_p(x) \ge 4 (x-p)^2$. Consequently, for any $k, p_n > 0,$ $$ \binom{n}{k} p_n^k (1-p_n)^{n-k} \le \sqrt{\frac{1}{n (k/n) (1-k/n)}} \exp( - n (k/n - p_n)^2).$$
For $k = \lfloor np_n\rfloor$ or $\lceil np_n\rceil$, we have $|k/n - p_n| \le 1/n$. So, for $n \ge 3, p_n \le \frac13,$ we have $$ P(X_n \in \{\lfloor np_n\rfloor, \lceil np_n\rceil\}) \le 2\sqrt{\frac{3}{(np_n - 1)}} \exp( -4/n),$$ which vanishes as $np_n \to \infty$.

In fact, a little bit more is true. For a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda,$ the median is between $\lambda - \log 2$ and $\lambda + \frac13$ [2]. If $\lambda$ is an integer, then from these bounds we can note that the median itself must be $\lambda$. So, if $np_n \to C$ for some positive $C \in \mathbb{N},$ we immediately conclude that $P(X_n \ge \mathbb{E}[X_n]) = \frac12 + O(p_n),$ where I'm using a standard bound on the KS distance between a Poisson and corresponding Binomial law (e.g., eq. 1.25 in [3]). If $C$ is not natural, but is large, then the error we end up with is again $O(1/\sqrt{C})$ in the worst case, essentially corresponding to $P(Z_C = \lceil C\rceil)$.

[1]: Kaas, R.; Buhrman, J.M. (1980). "Mean, Median and Mode in Binomial Distributions". Statistica Neerlandica. 34 (1): 13–18.
[2]: Choi, K. P. (1994). On the medians of gamma distributions and an equation of Ramanujan. Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, 121(1), 245-251.
[3]: Adell, J. A., Anoz, J. M., & Lekuona, A. (2009). The Kolmogorov Distance between the Binomial and Poisson Laws: Efficient Algorithms and Sharp Estimates. Journal of Inequalities and Applications, 2009, 1-13.

We know that $
X_n =\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$,where each $Y_k$ is a Bernoulli($p_n$) random variable.\
To apply Lyapunov's Central Limit Theorem (CLT) (you can check "\textit{Knowing the Odds An Introduction to Probability}" by John B. Walsh in page 179), we need to work with mean-zero random variables. For this reason, we define:
$
Z_k = Y_k - p_n,
$
where $Y_k \sim \mathrm{Bern}(p_n))$. The purpose of this definition is to ensure that $Z_k$ has mean zero. Specifically, we have:
$
E[Z_k] = E[Y_k - p_n] =E[Y_k] - p_n = p_n - p_n = 0.
$
This satisfies the requirement of Lyapunov's CLT that the random variables being summed have zero mean.\
The variance of $Z_k$ is the same as that of $Y_k$, since subtracting a constant does not change the variance.
$
\mathrm{Var}(Z_k) = \mathrm{Var}(Y_k) = p_n(1 - p_n).
$
Then,
$ S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k$ and $s_n^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm{Var}(Z_k) =np_n(1 - p_n).$\
Then we need to verify $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{s_n^{3}}\sum_{k=1}^n{E}\bigl[|Z_k^3|]=0$. It is not hard to verify that this limit goes to 0. By Lyapunov’s theorem,$
\frac{S_n}{s_n}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k}{s_n}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k-p_n}{s_n}=\frac{X_n - n\,p_n}{\sqrt{n\,p_n(1-p_n)}} \Longrightarrow{N}(0,1),$ in distribution.\
${P}[X_n \geq n p_n] = {P}\left(\frac{X_n - n p_n}{\sqrt{n p_n (1 - p_n)}} \geq 0\right) \to {P}[Z \geq 0] = \frac{1}{2}$
where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1) $. Equivalently, ${P}[X_n \geq {E}[X_n]] \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ as n goes to infinity.

Please let me know if I am mistaken, as I am just beginning to learn probability
